# Retrieve file name when regexp matches content

Tags: regex, bash, datetime, awk, text-files

So I have a directory which includes a bunch of text files, and inside each file there is a line that has the file's time stamp which has the format:

```
TimeStamp: mm/dd/yyyy
```

I am writing a script that takes in 3 inputs: month, date, and year, and I want to retrieve the name of the files that have the time stamps matched with the inputs.

I am using this line of code to match the files and output all the rows found to another file.

```
egrep 'TimeStamp: "$2"/"$3"/"$1"' inFile > outFile
```

However, I have not figured out a way to get the files names during the process.
Also, I believe there is a quick and simple way to do this with awk, but I am new to awk, so I am still struggling with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

- I'm assuming you want to BOTH capture matching lines AND, SEPARATELY, the names (paths) of the files that had matches (therefore, using just `egrep -l` is *not* enough).
- Based on your question, I've changed `'TimeStamp: "$2"/"$3"/"$1"'` to `"TimeStamp: $2/$3/$1"`, because the former would treat `$2`, ... as *literals* (would not expand them), due to being enclosed in a *single*-quoted string.

If you already have a *single* filename to pass to `egrep`, you can use `&&` to conditionally output that filename *if* that file contained matches (in *addition to* capturing the matches in a file).

```
egrep "TimeStamp: $2/$3/$1" inFile > outFile && printf '%s\n' inFile
```

When processing an **entire directory**, the **simple and POSIX-compliant** - but inefficient - approach is to process files in a loop:

```
 for f in *; do
   [ -f "$f" ] || continue  # skip non-files or break, if dir. is empty
   egrep "TimeStamp: $2/$3/$1" "$f" >> outFile && printf '%s\n' "$f"
 done
```

If you use `bash` and  ***GNU* `grep` or *BSD* `grep`** (also used on OSX), there's a **more efficient** solution:

```
egrep -sH "TimeStamp: $2/$3/$1" * | 
  tee >(cut -d: -f1 | sort -u > outFilenames) | 
  cut -d: -f2- > outFile
```

- Since `*` potentially also matches *directories*, `-s` suppresses error message stemming from (invariably failing) attempts to process them as *files*.
- `-H` ensures that each matching line is prefixed with the input filename followed by `:`
- `tee >(...) ...` sends input to both stdout and the command inside `>(...)`.
- `cut -d: -f1 | sort -u` extracts the matching filenames from the result lines, creates a sorted list without duplicates from them, and sends them to file `outFilenames`.
- `cut -d: -f2-` then extracts the matching lines (stripped of their filename prefix) and captures them in file `outFile`.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -l
```

Explanation

```
-l, --files-with-matches
  Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which
  output would normally have been printed. The scanning will stop on the first
  match. (-l is specified by POSIX.)
```

[Source](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep+-l)